# event listener not working when position absolute div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an event listener on a button. The button is inside div `div1`. When I click on another button, I make the `div1` `position:absolute`. However, the event listener on the button disappears. When I click on the button, nothing happens. Does anyone know why this is happening or how I can debug it?

Comment: Post your code please, and an absolute positioned div need a width and a height or else it collapse and its content with it

Comment: Are you dealing with `innerHTML` ?